# Force re-render React component when modified element HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a button component rendered like below. I can't modify the button component itself but I can modify the parent component that renders it. I want to make it so that when I modify the button element's disabled attribute elsewhere in the code (that is modify the DOM like `button.disabled = true`) **Given that I can't pass it from parent props**, the button component gets re-rendered. I tried to use useRef and useEffect hook but it didn't work. I think I used them wrongly. Is there anyway I can achieve what I want?

```
  const elementRef = useRef()
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(elementRef.current?.disabled)

  useEffect(() => {
    const buttonElement = elementRef.current
    buttonElement.addEventListener('disabled', handleDisabled)
  }, [elementRef.current])

  const handleDisabled = (e: any) => {
    setDisabled(e.target?.disabled)
  }

  return( <Button ref={elementRef} disabled={props.isDisabled || disabled}></Button> )
```

Comment: You can just set it directly with the state. I still don't really understand what you are asking here. `const [disabled, setDisabled} = useState(true)` then you have the follwing `<Button disabled={disabled}></Button>` then when you set the state it will render the button as disabled or not based on the state.

Comment: Can't, this component doesn't know when I conditionally changed the attribute. I want it to be depends on when I changes the attribute elsewhere.

Comment: Where elsewhere and how would you go about changing it? Sorry I'm just trying to figure out what you are asking here.

Comment: For example, change the html attribute of the button in a child component that can't modify the props of this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemingly are working in two different "worlds": ReactJs and the DOM.

I suggest to use only React, and never modify any DOM properties directly.

You don't show how you want to change the `disabled` attribute/property "elsewhere in the code", but I assume you want to do something like

```
const setMyButtonDisabled = function(){
    document.querySelector('#myButton').disabled = true;
}
```

React is simply not able to know about this change. You have to tell React explicitly, like:

```
// not recommended:
const setMyButtonDisabled = function( setButtonDisabledCallback ){
    document.querySelector('#myButton').disabled = true;
    setButtonDisabledCallback( true );
}
```

And then find a way to pass the props around, so that the desired components have it
(I can't know the relation between your code example and the "elsewhere").

But ideally you would never set the DOM buttonElements `.disabled` property, but set a React state `buttonDisabled` instead,
and then just pass that around to where ever you need it:

```
// recommended:
const setMyButtonDisabled = function( setButtonDisabledCallback ){
    setButtonDisabledCallback( true );
}
```